# How to validate multiply select using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I am trying to validate a multiply select using input filter, but every time I see a error. The error is "notInArray":"The input was not found in the haystack".(I use ajax but it doesn`t metter).
I will show part of my code to be more clear.

in Controller:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            $post = $request->getPost();
            $form = new \Settings\Form\AddUserForm($roles);// 
            $form->get('positions')
                         ->setOptions(
                                 array('value_options'=> $post['positions']));
```

//.... more code...

When I put print_r($post['positions']); I see:
array(0 => 118, 1 => 119)

in ..../form/UserForm.php I create the multiply element

```
$this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                    'id' => 'choosed_positions',
                ),
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'positions',



        ));
```

and in the validation file the code is:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'positions',
                        'required' => false,
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'InArray',
                                 'options' => array(
                                    'haystack' => array(118,119),
                                    'messages' => array(
                                        'notInArray' => 'Please select your position !'
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
```

What can be the reason every time to see this error, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does it fail no matter how many options you choose (zero, one or two)?

Comment: Also, does it fail if you don't make it multiple?

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($form->get('positions')->getValueOptions())

Comment: When I choose zero options I don`t see the error. When I choose one or more options I see the error. When I put the var_dump I see this:                          array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "118"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "119"
} Do you have idea what has to be the problem?

Comment: Did you try leaving out 'multiple' => 'multiple', and see if it works as a single select? I can't see anything obvious wrong.

Comment: I found the problem :) The problem was that the variable $post['positions'] has to be for example array(118=>'someText'), but it was array(0=>118)

Comment: Good job! Thanks for updating your question with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

**By default** selects *have attached* **InArray validator** in Zend Framework 2.

If you are adding new one - **you will have two**.

You should disable default one as follow:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'options' => array(
        'disable_inarray_validator' => true, // <-- disable
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'multiple' => 'multiple',
        'id' => 'choosed_positions',
    ),
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'positions',
));
```

And you should get rid of the additional error message.
Please let us know if that would helped you.